# Any way to make remote file MD5 generation faster?

Tags: laravel, ftp, md5, nfs

We store our files across two servers and have our main site on a small SSD server, we're using a NFS mount to enable viewing of the files on the main site.
We also display the MD5 on the file's download page.

Problem being, with large files the SSD server has to download the file before it MD5's it. This process can take awhile, making some pages take upto 10 seconds to load. We cant store the files locally as space is an issue.

Testing confirms that it's an issue with the download times causing the hangs.

---

```
root@SSD:/path/ md5sum file.zip a5044a42e53c6537165c6547a18da284
```

This server had had to grab the file remotely from the NFS mount location, all in all this took 11 seconds before we get the MD5.

---

```
root@eu:/path/ md5sum file.zip a5044a42e53c6537165c6547a18da284
```

This server, where the file is stored on the server without a mount MD5'ing takes a mere 1 second.

---

Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

Comment: a) Stop using MD5. b) What stops you to maintain a DB of hashes?

Comment: @deviantfan it's required for integrity checking in our field.

Comment: Integrity checking is ok, but MD5 is not. SHA2, SHA3...

Comment: @deviantfan we offer FTP uploading, hence tracking of files in a DB seems infeasible.
Also, sadly MD5 for integrity checking is the industry standard in the service we provide.

Comment: About the DB infeasible part: I see no reason for that. If you want the hash for a file, check if it is already in the DB and if the last change timestamp (saved in the DB too) is the same as the timestamp from the actual file (which can be queried without loading the content). If both conditions are fulfilled, use the hash, else calculate it from the content and insert it in the DB. Some file system monotoring could be used too...

Comment: @deviantfan This has been discussed, however some people are not happy that it'll still take 10 seconds or so to load if the file hasn't been accessed before.

Comment: @JoneDoes The nactivate some sort of file system monitoring on the file server which recalculates the hash for any changed file, without involving the other server.

Comment: @deviantfan Do you have any examples of such system? Most I've found online are only for core system files and or don't utilize a MySQL database. Thanks.

Comment: @vp_arth I'm not sure In understand what you're getting at. Nothing is wrong with using a checksum (I assume that's the problem, because of the bold marking). The problem is that MD5 is pretty weak, and even as checksum it's an unnecessary risk because better alternatives without disadvantages exist.

Comment: @vp_arth Did you read the part `an unnecessary risk because better alternatives without disadvantages exist`? Yes, as integrity check it's not as weak as it is when viewed from some security angles, but if I can have something much better for the same "price", why not?

Comment: @vp_arth For Sha2, there are similar tools, eg. sha512sum ... nothing yet for the Sha3 family, right. ... I don't want to and can't convince everyone; if you like MD5, use it. ... OP can't change the process anyways, so why are we discussing this here?

Comment: @JoneDoes You won't find something with Mysql built in, a bit scripting is necessary. With an terminal mysql client (or the full database) installed, a bash script should be enough. Triggered by cron, or more sophisticated in some connection with inotify; searching for files changed after xyz, calling the hash calculation program, and inserting the hash with some sql command agian to the DB.

Comment: @vp_arth sorry, we use laravel for our site, wanted to see if there's maybe some laravel sort of laravel function and or caching for this sort of thing.

Comment: This question is for unix.stackexchange.com. You can't to provide [mcve] here.

Answer (score 1):

No reason to calculate checksum at the request time.
Try to move this operation to `upload` study.

You can save checksum of `file.ext` in ther `file.ext.md5`.

Also, you must be sure there are not ways to edit files without updating this checksum too.

If you can't - add crontab with something like:

```
cd blob_directory ; md5sum * > check.md5
```

And you get list with `md5_hash filename` in `check.md5`

Comment: We can't have the function done on upload seeing as the we use FTP to upload, thus it not really being "linked" to the webserver as such.